# What widget can be used to have a list?

Tags: qt, widget, scrollbar

I'm using Qt creator to write c++ GUI application. I want to have a list to show the some guides to user and prefer to have a list with Scroll Bar. what widget can I use to this?

Comment: Did you look at QListWidget and QListView? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

For displaying lists, trees and tables, Qt has a set of [Model/View classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html).

In model/view, a subclass of [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) provides the data, which is then displayed by a [QAbstractItemView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html). Models can be "stacked" for rather flexible filtering, sorting and mapping of data (see e.g. [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html)).

There's basically now three ways to use them, of varying complexity, power and scalability:

1. So if you want full flexibility or have a large number of list entries (say, in the thousands), implement a [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html) with a [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html). While this is the most powerful solution, it's also the most complex one, and implementing a correct and efficient model has some pitfalls.
2. A simpler way would be to use [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) (or for an even simpler list of just strings, [QStringListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html)) and set that as model of a [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html). That might be far less daunting for a beginner, compared with having to implement your own models. It's not the most scalable version, but if you display e.g. 50 items, that just doesn't matter.
   You can still combine it with sorting and filtering via proxy models.
3. Then, the third and most simple way is to display a list is to use [QListWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html). It's a subclass of QListView that allows you to pass in the list items via QListWidgetItem, similar to QStandardItemModel. It basically "merges" the model functionality into the view class so that you don't have to touch models at all. While this is the simplest way, it's also the most inflexible one: You cannot use sort/filter proxy models when using a QListWidget.

To get started with Model/View, especially to people who are used to manage item-based lists, I recommend (2) and then move up to (1). If you just want a simple and immutable list of a couple items, (3) might as well do. If you find out later that you need sort/filter functionality, converting (3) into (2) later is usually rather easy, while converting (3) to (1) is a far more intrusive change.